# trouble with a user-defined function in aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to graduate from for loops by writing a function to plug into aggregate.  It is not going well.

The sample data is:

```
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
gdp <- c(3.5, 4.2, 5, 4, 4.2, 5, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 3.4, 4.0, 4.1, 4.3, 4.7)
df <- data.frame(group, gdp)
```

Goal of function, which is not working correctly, is that for each value of x (gdp) within a group, find the absolute difference between x and the smallest value of x, and the difference between x and the biggest value of x, and return whichever difference is smaller.  If there is only 1 value in a group, or if the value is the first or last item in a group, then the difference will be 0, in which case return 0.

Order matters, as I do not want it to collate all of group 1's; I want the function to be applied to each gdp value in a group, and then to move on to the next group.

The function is:

```
get_dist <- function(x){  
    a <- abs(x - min(x)) 
    b <- abs(x -max(x))   
    c <-  ifelse(a < b, a, ifelse(a = 0), 0, b) 
    return(c)
}
```

Then the final step, using aggregate:

```
edge_dist <- with(df, aggregate(group, list(gdp), get_dist))
```

Any advice on where I am going wrong? It is not returning what I hoped for.

Comment: In the definition of `c`, it looks like the first close paren should be after `b` rather than after `a = 0`.

Comment: You also need `a==0` rather than `a=0`.

Comment: great catch, Alex.  I am still getting nonsense output though.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10.  Another stupid mistake.  but am still getting incorrect output (just difference incorrect output).

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Try swapping the position of `group` and `list(gdp)` in the call to `aggregate()`. Per the docs, the subsetting factor comes after the variable to summarize.

Comment: vector returned should be: 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 0.5,

Comment: shoot, didn't get the whole thing: 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Looks like the `data.table` solution below gives the desired output, if you want to consider things besides `aggregate`

Comment: if you fix the things alex pointed out and use the id variable arvi created, then `with(df, ave(gdp, id, FUN = get_dist))` will work

Comment: @rawr So it does--thanks for the tip. wouldn't have thought of   'ave'

Comment: i mean, replace it with aggregate like you used before and it will work just fine. just easier to work with ave output than aggregate. but if you want to learn/load/use a data table pipeline..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table instead of aggregate:

```
library(data.table)

# step 1: assign unique groups
u_grps <- rle(df$group)$lengths
df$id <- rep(1:length(u_grps), u_grps)

# step 2: calculate your row-level stuff using data.table
data.table(df)[, min_abs_diff:=pmin(abs(gdp-max(gdp)), abs(gdp-min(gdp))), 
               by=id][]

# result:
#     group gdp id  min_abs_diff
#  1:     1 3.5  1           0.0
#  2:     1 4.2  1           0.7
#  3:     1 5.0  1           0.0
#  4:     2 4.0  2           0.0
#  5:     2 4.2  2           0.2
#  6:     2 5.0  2           1.0
#  7:     2 5.5  2           0.5
#  8:     2 6.0  2           0.0
#  9:     3 3.5  3           0.0
# 10:     1 3.4  4           0.0
# 11:     1 4.0  4           0.1
# 12:     1 4.1  4           0.0
# 13:     2 4.3  5           0.0
# 14:     2 4.7  5           0.0
```

Note: This example just prints the output. If you want to store in an object, use something like

```
df2 <- 
  data.table(df)[, min_abs_diff:=pmin(abs(gdp-max(gdp)), abs(gdp-min(gdp))), 
                 by=id]
```

Comment: On reading the clarifications in the comments to the questions, I think this is a far better answer than mine.

Comment: @arvi 1000  Gold, baby. danke shoen

Comment: `data.table` suitably has a `rleid` function. You can generate group id `by=rleid(group)`,

Comment: I think that's only in the 1.9.5 dev version? My 1.9.4 version (latest on CRAN) doesn't have `rleid()`. Good tip though!